# Are Anita and Arutha related?

Tags: riftwar-cycle, raymond-e-feist

In the books of the Riftwar cycle (by Raymond E. Feist), Anita and Arutha refer to each other as "cousins", however it is unclear how close of cousins they are (first cousins? second cousins?).

> Nevertheless, they marry and nobody seems to have any issue with this.

Furthermore, it is implied earlier that when speaking about royalty, the word "cousin" may actually refer to the fact that the royal families often intermarry, so everyone is kind of related to everyone else, even if the actual relation might be distant and difficult to trace.

So - has it ever been specified in the books (or interviews or whatever) just how closely or distantly Anita and Arutha are related by blood? I tried looking up on the Internet, but the closest I got was that their fathers had also been considered "cousins", which doesn't really say much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my reading of this, [official family tree](http://www.crydee.com/raymond-feist/family-tree), their exact familial relationship is "Unknown", but the tree goes back at least 4 generations before they have a shared ancestor.

I've pasted the relevant section for posterity

[image]

Comment: I'd say at least _5_, since "unknown number of generations" is highly unlikely to be "1."  Also note that Arutha's only blood connection is "brother of Lyam I" and it makes no claim about their ancestry whatsoever.

Comment: Actually there's nothing to say they couldn't be descended from one of the "Kings of the Isles (Unknown number of generations)."

Comment: I'll admit that I find this tree difficult to understand, and if I read it correctly there's nothing said about Arutha's and Anita's mothers, but I'll take it to mean that they are not related.